# How to show all records in table if my where condition gives empty output using Hive

Tags: sql, hive

show all records of table when my where condition returns empty output

```
EX:
Data:
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4

select * from table where x=1 ;
output
x,y
1,2

select * from table where x=10 ;
```

generally it gives me an empty output instead of that It should display entire records in table.

```
Output
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
```

In this case provided value doesn't occurs in x data so, it should show all the values in table

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from table
      where x = 1 
     )
select t.*
from t
union all
select t2.*
from table t2
where not exists (select 1 from t);
```

Another fun method works if `x` is unique:

```
select t.*
from table t left join
     table t2
     on t2.x = 1 
where (t2.x = 1 and t.x = 1) or (t2.x is null);
```